# Using topics with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am setting up `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to send notifications to an iOS app.
And I want to be able to send notifications, to all users who accepted to receive them.
After reading and experimenting quite a bit, my understanding is that (for my use case) I should set up some kind of general topic and then send each notification to this topic.
My question is: *how to create a topic first, and then how to register (a client) to a topic in my iOS Swift app?*

Though I tried to browse the net for info on that, I did not find much.

For information, I am using Xcode Version 10.1, iOS 12.1 and Swift 4.2.

Comment: You don't need to create a topic manually. Any subscription to a topic from the client will automatically create the topic if it doesn't exist.

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought there would be some kind of more "formal way" to do it, but in any case that answers the first part of the question.
I still have to figure out the second part: how do I subscribe? (in iOS Swift).
What I found and tried up to this point didn't work.

Comment: Let me extract some part of my project to show you, give me a moment.

Comment: OK. After searching a bit more it seems like the second part of my question has no answer. Reading this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions makes me think I should make use of a cloud function for that purpose. As an indication, the code is not given in Swift of Objectiv C. I could still be wrong though. But I am currently trying out a solution using a cloud function.

Comment: There is no need (nor even use) for Cloud Functions in subscribing a client to a topic. If you're having problems subscribing to a topic, share the code of what you've tried.

Comment: The problem is exactly this. Since I did not know how to do it, I hadn't tried anything. After reading this(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions), and seeing the code was not given for iOS (Swift of Objectiv C); I started to think a cloud function might be the way to go. It may not be the best way, but it seems like it could work. If you have a better and simpler solution, I will be happy to read.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1: Setting Up Firebase**

If you have yet to add Firebase to your project, it's all documented here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

You will need to start the configuration of Firebase. For my project, I started the configuration in the AppDelegate upon app start.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**Step 2: Requesting Authorization**

Assuming you have all the APNs Authentication Key/Certificates configured on your Apple Developer Portal and Firebase Cloud Messaging settings,

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/FIREBASE_PROJECT_NAME/settings/cloudmessaging/ios:APP_BUNDLE_ID

Next, you will need to request authorization for Push Notifications on the device. I've placed this in one of the first few UIViewControllers my project.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { (success, error) in

            guard success else { return }
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        })
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Device Token**

Upon registering for remote notification in step 2 with:

```
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

You will need to implement this delegate function in your AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    ...

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    }

    ...
}
```

Do note that the deviceToken received is in NSData, and the apnsToken required by Firebase is in String.

**Step 4: Topic Subscription**

Remember the delegate reference we set to AppDelegate in step 1?

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

You will need to implement its delegate function to let the app know that it Firebase did receive the token and it is ready to subscribe to a topic.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    ...

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/example")
    }

    ...
}
```

**Step 5: Validation**

One simple way to check if your app has successfully subscribed to a topic is to send a push notification via Firebase Console.

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/FIREBASE_PROJECT_NAME/notification